# How to Recompile DWM?

Tags: window-manager

I am about to run sudo apt-get install dwm on ubuntu 12.04.

When I was on arch linux dwm was installed to a folder and recompiled in the folder when you made changes to it. (Edit settings). I am sure you understand how important it is to be able to recompile the files as its the only way to make changes to dwm as far as I know.

Where exactly is the folder with the files installed to? Figure I should find this out before installing DWM blindly!

Answer (score 5):

If you plan on compiling your own `dwm`, you should get the source package instead of the binary one.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get build-dep dwm
cd directory/to/save/source/in
apt-get source dwm   # note that sudo is not required here.
```

Then, make any changes you want and build a binary package with `debuild`.

Answer (score 1):

That's what synaptic says:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/dwm.default
/usr/bin/dwm.web
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/dwm
/usr/share/doc/dwm/README
/usr/share/doc/dwm/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/dwm/copyright
/usr/share/icons
/usr/share/icons/dwm.png
/usr/share/lintian
/usr/share/lintian/overrides
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/dwm
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/dwm.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/dwm.default.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/dwm.web.1.gz
/usr/share/menu
/usr/share/menu/dwm
/usr/share/xsessions
/usr/share/xsessions/dwm.desktop
```